# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined(anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a good scroll when I click a navigation link and to send me to the specific div. This code in earlier project was working, but in this project I don't know the reason why is bug. I've tried to find a solution without asking a question but it was impossible.

this is the code:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li id="home-link" class="active"><a href="javascript:;">Home</a></li>
    <li id="about-link"><a  href="javascript:;">About</a></li>
    <li id="project-link"><a  href="javascript:;">Projekti</a></li>
    <li id="location-link"><a href="javascript:;">Lokacioni</a></li>
    <li id="plans-link"><a href="javascript:;">Planet</a></li>
    <li id="contact-link"><a  href="javascript:;">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here are the DIVS with 100%heights and widths that I want to scroll when I click to links.

```
$('#home-link').click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#myCarousel').offset().top }, 500);
});
$('#about-link').click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#about-us').offset().top }, 500);
});
$('#project-link').click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#projekti').offset().top }, 500);
});
$('#plans-link').click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#planet').offset().top }, 500);
});
$('#location-link').click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#location').offset().top }, 500);
});
$('#contact-link').click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#kontakti').offset().top }, 500);
});
```

Comment: It's working once than its not working anymore, but if I don't refresh the page, after some minutes it will work once again.

Answer (score -1):

I found the mistake that I did in code, the part of the jquery code was in a function and that caused the problem. So I just put in beginning of code, right above of

```
$(document).ready(functioN(){

});
```

and now work completely fine. Admin can close or delete this question.